# Writing and including C++ classes for Android JNI applications

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am new to using the Android NDK and JNI but have experience in both Java and C++. I'm trying to construct a MWE which shows that running a looping method natively will be faster than on a java class. I have imported the [hello-jni](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni/app/src/main) sample, converted the JNI code to be C++ compatible and it run as intended.

In the same project I have erased the sample code and started again but not changed the build settings. In order to compare performance, I have created two identical classes which do looping operations on an integer and an array. I have a Java class called `TestClassJava` and a C++ class (through `.h` and `.cpp` files) called `TestClassCpp` class. These class are as follows:

```
public class TestClassJava {

// Fields
private int id;
private int[] array;


// Constructor
public TestClassJava(int start_id) { // etc...  }

// Methods
public void incrementId() { // etc... }

public void labelArray() { // etc... }

public void loop() {
    while (id < 5000000) {
        incrementId();
        labelArray();
    }
}
}
```

The C++ header:

```
class TestClassCpp {

private:
    int id;
    int array[10];

public:
    TestClassCpp(int start_id);
    ~TestClassCpp();
    void incrementId();
    void labelArray();
    void loop();
};
```

And then the `.cpp`

```
#include "TestClassCpp.h"

// Constructor / Destructor
TestClassCpp::TestClassCpp(int start_id) { // etc... }    
TestClassCpp::~TestClassCpp() { }

// Methods
void TestClassCpp::incrementId() { // etc... }

void TestClassCpp::labelArray() { // etc... }

void TestClassCpp::loop() {
    while (id < 5000000) {
        incrementId();
        labelArray();
   }
}
```

*In the same jni directory as the header and cpp file* I have a file called `testclasswrapper.cpp` which contains the interface code between the java in `MainActivity` and the `TestClassCpp` `loop()` method. In `MainActivity` I have added

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("testclasswrapper");
}

public native void nativeLooper();
```

`nativeLooper()` is declared in the `testclasswrapper.cpp` file as

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_jnimwe_MainActivity_nativeLooper(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

// Get class
jclass cls = env->FindClass("TestClassCpp");

// Get method id of constructor
jmethodID constructor_method_id = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(I)V" );

// Instantiate object from C++ definition
jobject jobj = env->NewObject(cls,constructor_method_id);

// Get loop method id from object
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls,"loop","()V");

// Loop
env->CallVoidMethod(jobj,mid);

}
```

The application builds and deploys but fails to find the class with `jclass cls = env->FindClass("TestClassCpp");`. I have added the `moduleName` as `testclasswrapper` in the `build.gradle` file.

Error is

`JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' thrown in unknown throw location
06-23 16:07:14.617 12131-12131/com.example.jnimwe A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]     in call to GetMethodID`

so clearly it doesn't know about the class. I assume therefore that when building, gradle is not including the class definition when it build the library and is just building from the one file (`testclasswrapper.cpp`) rather than searching for all files and building and linking all of them. Adding an `#include "./TestClassCpp.h" in the`testclasswrapper.cpp` is greyed out so the definition of the class is not being included that way.

The original `hello-jni` example builds using ndk-build as I understand it. Similar answers all refer to a makefile called `Application.mk`. **There is no makefile in the hello-jni sample so there is no makefile in my example either**. How do I tell gradle to build the class I have created and link it into the library I'm loading?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm missing something, but from what you've mentioned above, it does not look like you have a `TestClassCpp` class in Java; which is what the `env->FindClass("TestClassCpp")` call is trying to do. Did you perhaps mean to look up `TestClassJava` in the `FindClass()` call?

Comment: Thanks @zenzelezz for getting back. I'm sorry the question is so long which might make it difficult to follow. You're right, I don't have a TestClassCpp in Java I have defined and implemented the whole class in C++. Are you saying that `FindClass()` only looks for Java classes? In which case how do I instantiate my C++ class in the JNI cpp file?

Comment: Yes, `FindClass()`, `Call<x>Method()` etc. are all meant to let native code tell Java to do work on Java classes/objects. Within your native code, you work in the same was as you would if Java wasn't involved. In your case I suppose basically `TestClassCpp c(x); c.loop();`

Comment: Right OK, thank you. The JNI environment has clearly got me confused with what syntax I should be using. That compiles and runs fine when I replace the JNI loop routine with `TestClassCpp* _c = new TestClassCpp(0); _c->loop();` but the native method is slower than a Java instantiation and loop which is a bit disappointing. Any thoughts on this @zenzelezz given that I don't make any interface calls in the `nativeLooper()` method? By the way, if you wanted to put your suggestion into an answer, I can accept if you like.

Comment: It is difficult to guess why one is faster than the other without seeing what actually happens inside `incrementId()` and `labelArray()`, it's possible that they technically do very different operations under the hood - a direct comparison is not necessarily easy. Also, how do you measure the time for the two?

Comment: @zenzelezz `incrementId()` is simply `id++;` and `labelArray()` is simply a for loop over the length of the array plus an assignment. Syntactically the Java and C++ code look the same for these simple operations. The timing is recorded using `System.nanotime()` before and after the calls to the Java and the native methods (including construction time for both) in the main activity. The array I loop over is only 20 elements long even though I'm looping 5000000 times so maybe that has something to do with it. High cost of method calls in native environment?